# oledb Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, syntax-error, oledb

I'm trying to import xlsx to datagrid using oledb.
but I'm getting this: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.I've read other related posts but didn't helped
this is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\alm1.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TXT" + "FROM [2$]", conn);
    DataSet dstxt = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(dstxt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dstxt.Tables[0];
```

can anyone help? I'm pretty sure it's a stupid mistake of me but can't figure it out.

Comment: Typo: Parses as `TXTFROM` add a space

Comment: `"SELECT TXT" + "FROM [2$]", conn` this is what happens when people write dynamic sql anyway.. try this instead it's sitting right in from of you `"SELECT TXT FROM [2$]", conn` and why do you have your select wrapped with `" "` 2 sets of quotes ..i would highly recommend making this query use Parameters as well as implement the `string.Format()` function it would make for reading this a lot cleaner and easier..

Comment: Alex K. add a space where?

Comment: Add a space between TXT and FROM so it reads: `TXT FROM`

Comment: As others have pointed out, `"SELECT TXT" + "FROM [2$]"` becomes "SELECT TXTFROM [2$]".  You need a space between "TXT" and "FROM". And you should get in the habit of using parameterized queries.

Comment: i used "SELECT TXT FROM [2$]", conn as DJ KRAZE suggested and worked...thank you all for you replies